# Transfer from JavaScript to jQuery, doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

The code which is working is here [Correctly working simple JS](http://jsfiddle.net/8hn5kgpw/157/)
Html:

```
pick a fruit:
<input type="text" id="newfruit">
<br>

<h1> Fruit Shelf:</h1>

<div id="div1">
    <ol id="fruits"></ol>
</div>

<h1>Basket:</h1>

<ol id="basket"></ol>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Submit' />
```

Js:

```
var list = document.getElementById('basket');
var fruitsshelf = document.getElementById("fruits");
var fruitslist = ["pear", "apple", "peach", "grapes", "strawberry", "melon"];
for (var j = 0; j < fruitslist.length; j++) {
    var newlist = document.createElement('li');
    newlist.id = 'listid'+j;
    newlist.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fruitslist[j]));
    fruitsshelf.appendChild(newlist);
}

function changeText2() {
    var newfruit = document.getElementById('newfruit').value;
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    var len = fruitslist.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (fruitslist[i] == newfruit) {

            entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newfruit));
            list.appendChild(entry);
            document.getElementById("listid"+i).remove();
            delete fruitslist[i];
        }
    }

}
```

I want to do the above code by using jQuery, here is what I have done now: [not working one using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/sbmp3apz/4/) 
Html:

```
 pick your fruit:
    <input type="text" id="newfruit">
    <br>

    <h1> Fruit Shelf:</h1>

    <div id="div1">
        <ol id="fruits"></ol>
    </div>

    <h1>Basket:</h1>

    <ol id="basket"></ol>
     <button>add fruit</button>
```

Js:

```
 var fruitslist = ["pear", "apple", "peach", "grapes", "strawberry", "melon"];
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var fruitsshelf = $('#fruits');
    for (var j = 0; j < fruitslist.length; j++) {
    var newlist =$('<li></li>');
    (newlist).attr('id', 'listid'+j);
    ('newlist').append(document.createTextNode(fruitslist[j]));
    document.querySelector('fruitsshelf').append(newlist);
}
  });


$('button').click(function () {
    var list = $('#basket');
    var newfruit = $('#newfruit').value;
    var entry = $('<li></li>');
    var len = fruitslist.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (fruitslist[i] == newfruit) {
            document.querySelector('entry').append(document.createTextNode(newfruit));
            document.querySelector('list').append(entry);
            $("#listid"+i).remove();
            delete fruitslist[i];
        }
    }

}
);
```

But it dosen't work, already replaced all of the simple method with jQuery methods, but doesn't work.
I don't know where is exactly wrong, help guys!

The fruit list should load up when the DOM is ready, and when you enter a fruit on the list and click submit, it should delete from the fruit shelf and add it to the basket.

Comment: `newlist.id` no no no, `newlist` is not an Element. It's a jQuery Element Array. And also, take a minute and think about what you are doing here, especially `$('fruitsshelf')` and `$('newlist')`. (Hint: There is nothing called a `newlist` tag or a `fruitsshelf` tag.) The selector works exactly the same as in vanilla JS's `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 but The newlist.id thing worked on my first link http://jsfiddle.net/8hn5kgpw/157/

Comment: Yeah but that's not jQuery.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 $(newlist).attr('id', 'listid'+j); that's what you mean right?

Comment: Now that's in correct jQuery syntax. (You might want to remove the `$` since `newlist` is already a jQuery object.)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Thanks Derek, but after I updated my js code as below, I removed the $ sign from all of the excising jquery objects, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Think about it in the jQuery way. Here's your code fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/sbmp3apz/5/ Take a look at it. With jQuery, there's no need for any `for`, no more `createTextNode`, etc.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Thanks Derek, can you post it as an answer, so I can give you a check and add you some reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's take a look here:

```
var fruitslist = [...];
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //some code you had
});

$('button').click(function () {
    //some more code
});
```

The whole point of `$(document).ready`, or simply `$` (this is the shorthand form), is to run your code after DOM is ready. However, here you decided to attach your `click` listener right at the beginning. This won't work because `$('button')` would return an empty list. Move it inside the `ready` listener so that `$('button')` would return the correct list.

On jsFiddle though, it defaults to automatically wrap all your codes in `$()`. (Take a look at the left sidebar.)

---

Next,

```
var fruitsshelf = $('#fruits');
for (var j = 0; j < fruitslist.length; j++) {
    var newlist =$('<li></li>');
    newlist.id = 'listid'+j;
    $('newlist').append(document.createTextNode(fruitslist[j]));
    $('fruitsshelf').append(newlist);
}
```

There are couple issues here. First of all, `newlist.id = 'listid'+j` would not work because `newlist` is a [special kind of] list of elements (it's a jQuery object.) That means, you will have to do

```
newlist.attr("id", "listid" + j);
```

to add an `id` attribute. Moving on,

```
$('newlist').append(document.createTextNode(fruitslist[j]));
```

I see that you are thinking with vanilla JS here. In jQuery, you can simply do this:

```
var newlist = $('<li>').attr("id", "listid" + j).text(fruitslist[j]);
```

and that's it! Now to append it to the `<ol>` tag, just use `appendTo`:

```
$('<li>', {id: "listid" + j}).text(fruitslist[j]).appendTo("#fruitsshelf");
```

There is even no need for the `newlist` variable. You can also get rid of the `for` loop, since `$.each` can take care of that for you. (Not to be confused with `.each` which is a non-static method, meanwhile `$.each` is a static method.)

---

Now to the `button` part:

```
var list = $('#basket');
var newfruit = $('#newfruit').value;
var entry = $('<li></li>');
var len = fruitslist.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (fruitslist[i] == newfruit) {
        $('entry').append(document.createTextNode(newfruit));
        $('list').append(entry);
        $("#listid"+i).remove();
        delete fruitslist[i];
    }
}
```

First issue, `$('entry')`: There is no such tag called `entry`.

In jQuery, methods can be chained. We don't like temporary variable names, that's why they added that in. Most things here can be rewritten without using variables (Though you should use them in certain case to increase readability):

```
$.each(fruitslist, function(i){
    var input = $('#newfruit').val();
    if (this == input) {
        $("<li>").text(input).appendTo("#basket");
        $("#listid" + i).remove();
        delete fruitslist[i];
    }
});
```

Now the code is much cleaner.

In this demo I made, I even get rid of the `id`s for all the list items: http://jsfiddle.net/sbmp3apz/5/

---

Just remember, `$("cssSelectorHere")` does not return a node, instead, it returns a list similar to `document.querySelectorAll`. And also keep in mind that jQuery methods can be chained (to save you some typings to do!)

Comment: Derek... ++ for your really amazing effort and detailed explanations

Comment: You are really a pro man on JavaScript !!! Especially on JQuery! Amazing! I saw on your profile you said "JQuery will change the world". Well, I don't know if JQuery is gonna change the world, what I know now is I will need a lot of work to do. Thanks bud, I'll read it through and learn a lot!

Comment: @kwokkaki - jQuery indeed is an amazing library which significantly simplify the work you have to do when trying to directly manipulate DOM. There are many more libraries and frameworks if you want even more abstraction and less typing, such as AngularJS. Here's the same thing as yours but written in AngularJS: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/hous919q/ You will be fascinated by how few codes you have to write. In AngularJS you don't even have to touch the DOM. It simply handles everything for you! :D

Answer (score 0):

in jsfiddle you have that jquery url add.

```
var fruitslist = ["pear", "apple", "peach", "grapes", "strawberry", "melon"];
var fruitsshelf = $('#fruits');
$( document ).ready(function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < fruitslist.length; j++) {
        var create = $('<li>').attr('id',fruitslist[j]).text(fruitslist[j]);
        fruitsshelf.append(create);
  }
});
$('button').click(function () {
    var newfruit = $('#newfruit').val();
    var entry = $('<li>').text(newfruit);
    fruitsshelf.append(entry);
});
```